# Parachain config for Rococo public test network

Tags: parachain, rococo, cumulus, chainspec, test-network

How to config a locally tested parachain to connect it to the Rococo public test-network?
I mean on the startup phase (before the Rococo Slot Request Form), following the Cumulus tutorial: after obtaining a paraID how can I run the substrate-parachain-template to get the onBoarding parathread status on Rococo ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can follow this tutorial to connect to Rococo: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk#testing-a-parachain

Answer (score 0):

This is the section of the tutorial that you want to check for registering your parathread. https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/connect-parachain/#registration-transaction